# Best practices to implement an Interface across different project modules

Tags: spring-boot, multi-module, clean-architecture, dependency-inversion

I have a multi module application, consisting of an interface in `module A` and an implementation in `module B`. Module A is linked to module B using dependency inversion where `module B` is injected into `module A` via @Autowiring. The main application will implement both `module A and B` and thus will not have any error. However, if `module A` is running on its own, it will not be able to find the implementation and throw an error.

May I seek your advice how should we best implement dependency inversion to follow CLEAN architecture and also to allow `module A` to run on its own?

Hope this diagram gives a better illustration of our problem
[image: Multimodule Diagram]